# Excel sharing violation error

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, anti-virus

Good day!

Whenever I save an excel file, this error message always appears:

- Your changes could not be saved to "xxxx.xlsm" due to a sharing violation. Try saving to a different file.

I've tried doing the following things below but the error still exists:

- Reinstall Microsoft Excel
- Disable antivirus while saving file
- Move contents of existing file to a fresh excel file
- Unchecked folder indexing under Folder properties > advanced
- Did a system restore (But the error returned a few days after)

Do you guys know any solution to this problem? I've been experiencing this error for almost 3 weeks and still can't find any solution.

Your help is much appreciated!

Other information:

- Using Windows 7 64bit
- Antivirus = Avast
- Using Microsoft Excel 2010

Comment: From my readings, it seems that it is due to the antivirus. Do you have Windows Defender activated, on top of Avast? There's a good explanation in [the 2 comments here](http://www.proposedsolution.com/solutions/ms-excel-sharing-violation/#comment-134477), as well as possible solutions.

Comment: I checked my list of programs and noticed that a program called **Bytefence (anti-malware)** program was installed on my computer last week. I don't know how it got there but I uninstalled it and I'm no longer experiencing the problem. Thank you!